# Tango Constructor app has stopped working

Tags: google-project-tango

Recently I was trying to use tango Constructor app for scanning and I noticed that it was getting stuck a lot. So, I tried updating it in playstore. But it seems the app has been removed from the playstore. Without any information. Any idea whats happening?

Also, where does the Tango Constructor app store the models generated? I could not find them using the file explorer app. Any help will be appreciated.